# How to use a personal function in Matlab within Mathematica utilizing Matlink?

Tags: packages, interoperability, matlab, matlink

## Problem description

I've written a function in Matlab as follows:

```matlab
function z = testfuncadd(x,y)
z = x + y;
end
```

I want to use this function within Mathematica utilizing [Matlink](http://matlink.org/documentation/). I tried the two methods below but none of them were useful.

- Using command `MEvaluate["testfuncadd(2,3)"]` in Mathematica.
- Using command `MATLABCell[]` and the command `testfuncadd(2,3)`.

The two methods above have a common error information `Undefined function 'testfuncadd' for input arguments of type 'double'`.

I've already added the folder that contains the function `testfuncadd.m` into the Matlab Path. But this still didn't solve the question. On the other hand, I can successfully call the built-in function of Matlab within Mathematica such as `eig` using the command `MEvaluate["eig(magic(3))"]`.

What else can I do to solve this problem?

## Version information

- Matlab: `23.2.0.2391609 (R2023b) Update 2`
- Mathematica: `"13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"`
- Windows 10

Comment: I would suspect path problems.  What does `MEvaluate["path"]` give you?

Comment: @mikado Thank you for your comment. I've figured out the solution(I just made it work well while I don't know the exact reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the problem but I'm not pretty sure about the reason. As suggested by @mikado in the comment, this time I used the command

```matlab
addpath("your folder directory which contains the function you want to implement")
```

in Matlab instead of using
[image]
button in Matlab. Things just worked out and I don't know why.

Anyway, to run a personal function in Matlab within Mathematica utilizing MATLink, you just need to make sure the package MATLink is installed [as documented](http://matlink.org/#installation) and add the folder directory that contains the function you want to implement into the path of Matlab. You can try both the command method `addpath` or the GUI button add `Set Path`.

## Edit

Using `addpath` command in Matlab might not really add the required file to the path. One only needs to do it in Mathematica, in other words, running the following code in Mathematica

```mathematica
MEvaluate["addpath(\"Your needed file path\")"];
```

Then, I think everything will work as expected.

Comment: could you please give the complete answer with details. It will be useful for others if you type exactly what you have done within Mathematica.